# Shiny slider on logarithmic scale

Tags: r, slider, shiny

I'm using Shiny to build a simple web application with a [slider](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sliders.html) that controls what p-values should be displayed in the output.

How can I make the slider act on a logarithmic, rather than linear, scale?

At the moment I have:

```
sliderInput("pvalue",
            "PValue:",
            min = 0,
            max = 1e-2,
            value = c(0, 1e-2)
),
```

Thanks!

Comment: `input_slider` from `ggvis` has a `map` argument. You can use `ggivs` directly, or look at the implementation of the map argument.

Comment: I think I could get a very simple javascript to solve this, shouldn't be more than a few lines, could you show us exactly what you want though?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wasn't sure exactly what you wanted as the output, but what I did was have the possible p-values be [0, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01].  If you want something a little different, hopefully this answer is a good enough starting point.

Basically, first I created an array that holds the values of the numbers (0, 0.0000.1, ...), and then I just use the special update function from the slider's API to make these values stick to the slider.  It's pretty simple once you figure out how to use the slider's API.  Also, for some reason running this inside RStudio looks weird, but in a browser it's fine. Also, note that I have a 5ms delay because I want to make sure this runs after the slider gets initialized. Not the cleanest solution, there's probably a better way to do that, but it works.

```
library(shiny)

JScode <-
  "$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      var vals = [0];
      var powStart = 5;
      var powStop = 2;
      for (i = powStart; i >= powStop; i--) {
        var val = Math.pow(10, -i);
        val = parseFloat(val.toFixed(8));
        vals.push(val);
      }
      $('#pvalue').data('ionRangeSlider').update({'values':vals})
    }, 5)})"

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(JScode))),

    sliderInput("pvalue",
                "PValue:",
                min = 0,
                max = 1e-2,
                value = c(0, 1e-2)
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
))
```

Comment: OP/bounty asker: is this what you wanted?

Comment: This looks really good, but something strange happens with the labels, it's like they are all concatenated - any ideas?

Comment: Hmm on my browser they look fine (in RStudio they're all bunched together). It looks weird to you in an actual browser? I think that may be because of the floating point issue (if you look at the numbers, they're like ".00010000000000002"), so the solution would be to either round them to like 5 digits or to construct the numbers as strings instead of as 10^-n

Comment: I updated my answer , I just used `parseFloat(...toFixed())` to make sure it only displays the first 8 decimal points. Notice that the ionrangeslider does seem to have a weird bug where it inserts commas as a thousands separator even to the right of the decimal point (10000 is correctly shown as 10,000, but 0.0001 is incorrectly shown as 0.0,001).  That's a separate issue that I don't think is part of the responsibility of this answer

Comment: You were right, but that change has sorted it regardless. This is just what I was after, good to have this answered - up to OP to accept if satisfied now

Comment: @daatali: I'm trying these steps but it's not quite working. I've posted here in case you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853223/r-shiny-using-log-scale-slider-for-values-from-0-01-to-100

Answer (score 18):

**UPDATE (May 2018):**

This is now possible through the `shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput()` control. You can specify custom steps (e.g., logarithmic intervals), and the slider steps through those. The downside is that you need to specify each step, rather than a max and min and have the slider calculate the steps, but it works well for this kind of application.

Small example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput("pvalue2","PValue:",
                            choices=c(0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01),
                            selected=0, grid = T)
)
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: a little example could be great!

Comment: @agenis Edited to include example. Thanks for correcting the function name!

Answer (score 16):

Not sure this thread is still active but just in case wanted to add a more generic way of "logifying" an inputSlider using the prettify function attribute of the ionRangeSlider rather than overwriting the values with the advantage being that you can define the min, max, step and default value of the inputSlider as usual and then all that happens on the Javascript side is a change of the displayed values (two options presented, one for numeric output, one for scientific notation):

```
library(shiny)

# logifySlider javascript function
JS.logify <-
"
// function to logify a sliderInput
function logifySlider (sliderId, sci = false) {
  if (sci) {
    // scientific style
    $('#'+sliderId).data('ionRangeSlider').update({
      'prettify': function (num) { return ('10<sup>'+num+'</sup>'); }
    })
  } else {
    // regular number style
    $('#'+sliderId).data('ionRangeSlider').update({
      'prettify': function (num) { return (Math.pow(10, num)); }
    })
  }
}"

# call logifySlider for each relevant sliderInput
JS.onload <-
"
// execute upon document loading
$(document).ready(function() {
  // wait a few ms to allow other scripts to execute
  setTimeout(function() {
    // include call for each slider
    logifySlider('log_slider', sci = false)
    logifySlider('log_slider2', sci = true)
  }, 5)})
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(JS.logify))),
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(JS.onload))),

  sliderInput("log_slider", "Log Slider (numbers):",
              min = -5, max = 3, value = -4, step = 1),

  sliderInput("log_slider2", "Log Slider (sci. notation):",
              min = -5, max = 3, value = 1, step = 0.5),

  br(),

  textOutput("readout1"),
  textOutput("readout2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$readout1 <- reactive({
    paste0("Selected value (numbers): ", input$log_slider, " = ", 10^input$log_slider)
  })

  output$readout2 <- reactive({
    paste0("Selected value (sci. notation): ", input$log_slider2, " = ", 10^input$log_slider2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: This does not work with the RStudio browser, bute does in chrome and FF

Comment: This works nicely but not when the sliderInput is created on the server side in a renderUI. The problem is that the script fires before object is created (if I set the wait time long enough it works). Any good fix?

Comment: I found a way. inserting the call to JS.onload into the render UI does the trick. `session$sendCustomMessage(type='jsCode', list(value = JS.onload))`. You also need this in the ui: `tags$head(tags$script(HTML('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsCode", function(message) { eval(message.value); });')))`

Comment: I also had to set `'prettify_enabled' : true` inside the `.update({ })` call

Answer (score -2):

The reason the question hasn't gotten more attention is that its hard to answer.  To do what the asker wants, you have to write javascript and inject it into the webpage.  Below is code I adapted to properly format a `shiny` slider as dates.  I haven't tried to modify it for logarithmic because I only learned enough javascript to tinker with this one script, and then promptly deleted it from memory to make room for more important things like the seasonal beer menu at the bar down the block.

Anyhoo:

```
    output$selectUI <-
        renderUI(
            list(sliderInput(inputId = "target", label = "Date",
                                             min = 0, max = diff_months(targetEnd(),targetStart()) - 1,
                                             value = diff_months(targetEnd(),targetStart()) - 1,
                                             animate = animationOptions( loop = T)),
                     singleton(HTML(
                '
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            var monthNames = [ "Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May", "June",
            "July", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec." ];
            var endDate = new Date(',
                year(Sys.Date()),',', month(Sys.Date())
                ,', 1);
            var slider = $("#dates").slider();
            var labels = slider.domNode.find(".jslider-label span");
            labels.eq(0).text("Jan., 1962");
            labels.eq(1).text([monthNames[endDate.getUTCMonth() +1], endDate.getUTCFullYear()].join(", "));
            // override the default "nice" function.
            slider.nice = function(value) {
alert("hi")
                var ref_date = new Date(1962, 1, 1);
                var slider_date = new Date(ref_date.setMonth(ref_date.getMonth() + value));
                return [monthNames[slider_date.getUTCMonth()], slider_date.getUTCFullYear()].join(", ");
            }

            $(slider).trigger("slidechange");
            })

    $(document).ready(function() {
                var monthNames = [ "Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May", "June",
                    "July", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec." ];
      var slider = $("#target").slider();
            var labels = slider.domNode.find(".jslider-label span");
          labels.eq(0).text([monthNames[', month(targetStart()) +1, '],', year(targetStart()), '].join(", "));
            labels.eq(1).text([monthNames[', month(targetEnd()) + 1, '], ', year(targetEnd()), '].join(", "));


      // override the default "nice" function.
      slider.nice = function(value) {
alert("hi")
        var ref_date = new Date(', year(targetStart()), ', ', month(targetStart()),',1 );
        // each slider step is 4 weeks, translating to 24 * 3600 * 1000 milliseconds
        var slider_date = new Date(ref_date.setMonth(ref_date.getMonth() + value - 1));

        return [monthNames[slider_date.getUTCMonth()],
                slider_date.getUTCFullYear()].join(", ");
      }

            $(slider).trigger("slidechange");
    })
  </script>
            ')
            )
        )
)
```

Comment: Well, I'd say for it to be an answer to the question, it really needs to address the logarithmic aspect!

Comment: I don't think so.  Defining the mapping is trivial (if you know javascript).  The hard part is figuring out how to get shiny to do that.  The code above took about 4 days worth of time to get working, of which perhaps 10 minutes was spent on the code to create the date format.  If that.

Comment: Great! So making those changes so that it answers the question should be easy...!

Comment: Wow, I guess I should be more careful about picking who I try to help.  Good luck!

Comment: Help is always greatly appreciated, however I'm not going to award the bounty (and I assume the OP won't accept the answer) if it's actually for a different question (even if you believe the difference is subtle). This might be what is needed to give someone a kick along, but it's not the answer to the question. Would be awesome if you edited it so that it could be accepted/awarded

Comment: can you clarify exactly what kind of values to show? should the labels change, or just the slided values?

Answer (score -2):

I don't have shiny at the moment with me, I have extended the range a little, what will happen if you try something like this:

```
sliderInput("pvalue",
            "PValue:",
            min = 1e-02,
            max = 1e+02,
            value = -10^seq(-2, 2)
),
```

your post it is mentioned 1e-2, i have used 1e-02, i checked like below

```
> 1e-2==1e-02
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The value parameter only accepts one or two values (see http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/sliderInput.html). The only ways of doing this are either to show the `log(pValue)` on the scale or the rather neat JavaScript solutions others have posted.