# Uneven spacing on R Shiny sliderInput

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I would like to create a sliderInput for a Shiny app which accepts a year as input, with all possible integer values from a variable time in the past (e.g. 1866) to the current year. Most users will only be interested in recent years, for for better UX I would like uneven spacing on the slider.

Note that answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502870/shiny-slider-on-logarithmic-scale) exist for using a slider with a nonlinear scale - this is not what I am looking for. The acceptable values for the slider should still be any integer in the range (and nothing else), but I would like the values to be spaced differently, like in the cartoon example below (ticks displayed every 5 years pre-1980 for visibility).

[image: A schematic depiction of uneven spacing]

Comment: Look into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502870/shiny-slider-on-logarithmic-scale maybe it can help you

Comment: @BertilNestorius I included a link to that very question in my question... It's not what I'm looking for. "Note that answers like this one exist for using a slider with a nonlinear scale - this is not what I am looking for. The acceptable values for the slider should still be any integer in the range (and nothing else), but I would like the values to be spaced differently."

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using `shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput`, which allows you to supply a character vector of choices.

Comment: Unfortunately as far as I can see if I want any integer in the range to be an option, then this would still be a linear scale. You are right though that this may be a good compromise - by restricting the number of available choices I could have a nonlinear scale.