# Creating a categorical sliderInput within a rendered UI in R shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, ion-range-slider

I'm trying to create a categorical (as opposed to numeric) slider in shiny using `sliderInput`. Thanks to Dean Atali's answer here ([Shiny slider on logarithmic scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502870/shiny-slider-on-logarithmic-scale)), I'm able to create the slider.

However, I need to create the slider in `server` and pass it to the UI via `renderUI` and `uiOutput`. But, when I move the `sliderInput` into a `renderUI` call on the server-side, it no longer works. Here are two examples: the first one showing how the categorical slider works (when not using `renderUI`/`uiOutput`), and the second one showing how the categorical slider does not work (when using `renderUI`/`uiOutput`).

**WORKING EXAMPLE (slider created in the UI)**

```
library(shiny)
JScode <-
  "$(function() {
setTimeout(function(){
var names = ['Unrated', 'Emerging', '&nbsp;',  'Formative', '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;', 'Developed', '&nbsp;'];
var vals = [];
for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
var val = names[i];
vals.push(val);
}
$('#pvalue').data('ionRangeSlider').update({'values':vals})
}, 7)})"

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(JScode))),
    textOutput('texty'),
    sliderInput("pvalue",
                "PValue:",
                min = 0,
                max = 7,
                value = 0
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$texty <- renderText({
      input$pvalue
    })
  }
))
```

**Non-working example (slider created in `server`)**

```
library(shiny)
JScode <-
  "$(function() {
setTimeout(function(){
var names = ['Unrated', 'Emerging', '&nbsp;',  'Formative', '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;', 'Developed', '&nbsp;'];
var vals = [];
for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  var val = names[i];
  vals.push(val);
}
$('#pvalue').data('ionRangeSlider').update({'values':vals})
}, 7)})"

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(JScode))),
    textOutput('texty'),
    uiOutput('uu')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$texty <- renderText({
      input$pvalue
    })
    output$uu <- renderUI({
      sliderInput("pvalue",
                  "PValue:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 7,
                  value = 0
      )
    })
  }
))
```

How do I make the slider show the categories (rather than numbers) when the slider is generated in `server`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving the line where you include the JavaScript to the `renderUI` (and wrapping it in a `div` together with the input element so both are returned to the UI) seems to do the trick, working example below. I am no JavaScript expert, but I assume the reason for this is is that in your case, the DOM element does not exist yet and thus the JavaScript code is not attached - but someone please correct me if I am wrong in this assumption.

I added two pieces of code below, one with a categorical slider with interactive labels as suggested by @agenis in the comments, and another with your code slightly adjusted to make your example work.

Hope this helps!

---

**1. Interactive categorical slider**

[image]

```
library(shiny)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    numericInput('nlabs','number of labels:', min=3,max=10,value=3),
    checkboxInput('rev','Reverse?',value=FALSE),
    textOutput('texty'),
    uiOutput('uu')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$texty <- renderText({
      input$pvalue
    })

    output$uu <- renderUI({

      # Create labels
      my_labs = sort(LETTERS[1:input$nlabs],decreasing = input$rev)
      my_labs = paste(sapply(my_labs,function(x){paste0("'",x,"'")}),collapse=",")
      # Create the JS code
      JScode <-paste0(
        "$(function() {
setTimeout(function(){
var names = [",
        my_labs,
        "];
var vals = [];
for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
var val = names[i];
vals.push(val);
}
$('#pvalue').data('ionRangeSlider').update({'values':vals})
}, 7)})")

      # Return the div with the JS Code and the sliderInput.
      div(
        tags$head(tags$script(HTML(JScode))),
        sliderInput("pvalue",
                    "PValue:",
                    min = 0,
                    max = 7,
                    value = 0
        )
      )
    })
  }
))
```

---

**2. Working version of your code**

```
library(shiny)
JScode <-
  "$(function() {
setTimeout(function(){
var names = ['Unrated', 'Emerging', '&nbsp;',  'Formative', '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;', 'Developed', '&nbsp;'];
var vals = [];
for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
var val = names[i];
vals.push(val);
}
$('#pvalue').data('ionRangeSlider').update({'values':vals})
}, 7)})"

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textOutput('texty'),
    uiOutput('uu')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$texty <- renderText({
      input$pvalue
    })
    output$uu <- renderUI({
      div(
        tags$head(tags$script(HTML(JScode))),
        sliderInput("pvalue",
                    "PValue:",
                    min = 0,
                    max = 7,
                    value = 0
        )
      )
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: I guess the finality of this is to make the list of labels reactive, no? so it might be dynamically changed

Comment: @agenis That makes sense! I added code for that too.

Comment: The reason for doing this on the server side, @agenis, is because I have a use case in which I need to do dozens and dozens of these sliders, and the sliders not to have different starting default values based on other inputs.

Comment: @FlorianGreat answer. Thank you!

Comment: @user2741035, glad I could help. Did this solve your issue? If so, please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to mark the question as resolved, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use function `sliderTextInput` from package [`shinyWidgets`](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets) :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textOutput(outputId = 'texty'),
    uiOutput(outputId = 'uu')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$texty <- renderText({
      input$pvalue
    })
    output$uu <- renderUI({
      sliderTextInput(
        inputId = "pvalue",
        label = "PValue:",
        grid = TRUE,
        choices = c("Unrated", "Emerging", "Formative", "Developed")
      )
    })
  }
))
```

[image]