# r shiny sliderInput with exact values instead of evenly divided range

Tags: r, shiny

So the API of the `sliderInput` widget allows you to set a min and a max and then it gives you a range between the min and max where the range is evenly divided. Is it possible to give `sliderInput` a vector of all the values you want and have the slider only able to land in one of those values in the vector?

Comment: It's a good question. Maybe you can do it by having an integer range but changing the labels on the ticks marks. It might need to be done in javascirpt or css though. I don't think shiny includes that functionality.

Comment: Why not use dropdown with all possible values then?

Comment: @RonakShah The victor is numeric with natural order. And there could be hundreds of values. Thus a slider range is more appropriate than a dropdown

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49490395/creating-a-categorical-sliderinput-within-a-rendered-ui-in-r-shiny), though not addressing your exact question, may point you in a useful direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the `sliderTextInput` from `shinyWidgets` does what you want. Though on the slider, all values are equally separated and not proportionnally.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sliderTextInput(
    inputId = "myslider",
    label = "Choose a value:", 
    choices = c(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31),
    grid = TRUE
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe(print(input$myslider))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```